# Cant install package rwf on multiple R versions

Tags: r

I cant install package `rwf`. I am getting error:

`Installing package into ‘C:/Users/This_user/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rwf’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)`

Same situation happened for version 3.4.0. I cant figure out what is a problem here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no `rwf` package on cran at all. But the first hit is always the `forecast` package with the function `rwf`. Do you want that one?

Comment: `> install.packages("thisPackageSurelyDoesNotExist")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘thisPackageSurelyDoesNotExist’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
>`

Comment: I was looking for `snaive` function. I couldnt call it for some reason but it works after I upgraded my R and reinstalled `forecast` package. Thank you anyway.